# OpenShot opens .webm file as audio

Tags: video, openshot, webm

Tried to edit this file:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Acute_leukemia.webm

in OpenShot 1.4.3, which is what the Ubuntu Software Store has and what the OpenShot site says is current.  This is on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

The file imports, but appears as an audio file, not a video file in OpenShot.  Audio will play, but there's no video.

Attempting to play the file with "Videos" results in a popup error complaining that a necessary audio codec is missing.  Video will play, but without audio.

Firefox will play the file with both audio and video, even from the file on disk.

Ubuntu says the file is VP9 video and "audio/x-unknown" audio.

Video player says ON2 VP9 video and "audio/x-unknown" audio in a Matroska container.

OpenShot just says "Audio".  Firefox just says "Video".

Do I need more codecs? From where?

Answer (score 0):

I just booted a trusty VM on my computer at home (I'm still in the office) and tried to load the file in OpenShot and VLMC, not luck.

*On2* my be a bit confusing to read, that's the company that built all the VP codecs, until Google [bought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On2_Technologies#Acquisition_by_Google) them. This version of OpenShot was [released in October 2012](https://launchpad.net/openshot/1.4/1.4.3), before VP9 was released and the developers since then tried to put out the next release, first 1.5 that apparently didn't make it, now 2.0.

So it seems that typical video editors in 14.04 cannot read this file. (I haven't tried Kdenlive, but it's installed on the host.) The greatest chance of success would be convert the video to VP8, we would still need a more recent build of ffmpeg for a conversion from VP9 to VP8 though. You could install another Linux distribution, build ffmpeg on your own or [pick the Windows binary](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) and run it with Wine. (It's under `bin/` in the zip, place it in the same folder as the video and replace `ffmpeg-win64` in the example with the actual `.exe` filename.)

That's what the command (1st line) and the output will look like:

```
$ wine64 ffmpeg-win64 -i Downloads/Acute_leukemia.webm -c:a copy -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 0 Downloads/Acute_leukemia_.webm
err:menubuilder:init_xdg error looking up the desktop directory
ffmpeg version N-77556-g4160900 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavcodec     57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavformat    57. 21.100 / 57. 21.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 22.100 /  6. 22.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Downloads/Acute_leukemia.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.7.101
  Duration: 00:10:18.24, start: 0.007000, bitrate: 697 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 1812x1018, lossless, SAR 1:1 DAR 906:509, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
File 'Downloads/Acute_leukemia_.webm' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
fixme:msvcrt:MSVCRT__wsopen_s : pmode 0x01b6 ignored
[libvpx @ 000000000038e480] v1.5.0
[webm @ 000000000038cd00] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, webm, to 'Downloads/Acute_leukemia_.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.21.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 1812x1018 [SAR 1:1 DAR 906:509], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn,30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.20.100 libvpx
    Side data:
      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=18547 fps=8.3 q=0.0 Lsize=   46960kB time=00:10:18.23 bitrate= 622.3kbits/s speed=0.277x
video:40026kB audio:6591kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.735802%
```

And here the proof that the file now loads in OpenShot:

[image]

I'm a bit surprised that the Video got smaller, it should have been bigger especially since `-crf 10` should result in higher bitrates than the default settings, it's either not high enough (try values lower than 10), or my parameters are wrong for VP8. (They work with VP9.)

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9
- If you just want to cut the video you may want to have a look at mkvtoolnix-gui ([store link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mkvtoolnix-gui/), but better get the new GUI from the developers site) and split the file with timecodes.
- Apparently Opus is already supported by OpenShot, if not try Vorbis, just replace `copy` with `libvorbis -q:a 4` for Vorbis 128 kbps (may be a bit too high).

It seems to work, but the encode was rather slow here. I cannot check if the result is proper, VRDP is very laggy here even with conservative settings.